# is this line of code correct re memory management (re NSDate copy)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, autorelease

is this line of code correct re memory management (re NSDate copy)?

I have a class with properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate* start;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate* coreWeStart;
```

Now in the init method, assuming self.start is already set, is this correct re setting the coreWeStart to the same date:

```
    self.coreWeStart= [[self.start copy] autorelease];
```

Just double checking my understanding that:

1. needs a 'copy' as otherwise it would refer to the same object and
2. needs an autorelease as I did do a copy

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say kind of, but it could still be done better.  Specifically, you could do:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate* coreWeStart;
```

...and then:

```
self.coreWeStart = self.start;
```

...to get the same thing with less code.  Also be sure to do `self.coreWeStart = nil` in dealloc (and `self.start = nil` too).

Comment: I guess unless you want the coreWeStart property to refer to some other external property at some point in the future (ie the property is retain for some other reason).

Comment: can I check: (a) is there any way around having to set them to nil in dealloc? (b) do you think using copy may lead to confusion later if developers don't monitor the way the property was set [i.e. is it mostly normal to use "retain" most of the time]

Comment: I generally like to explicitly release my memory ([start release]), rather than just setting to nil. Problem with that approach is that if someone accidentally types start=nil instead of self.start=nil, the memory will leak.

Comment: For future developers it usually doesn't matter if you use `retain` or `copy`. Since `NSDate` is immutable the only thing that `copy` will do is `retain` anyway. And I wouldn't consider retain `normal`. I usually use copy, except for mutable classes.

Comment: @Greg - (a) Yes, you can call `release` on them, as per RedBlueThing's comment.  (b) It depends on the developer, really.  In general, `copy` is used for properties that might be subject to change elsewhere in the code.  For instance, if you have a property of type `NSString` someone may pass you an `NSMutableString` instance and then change its value afterwards, which could cause issues if the property is declared as `retain`.  Declaring it as `copy` avoids the problem.  That said, `NSDate` has no mutable subclass, so the "normal" declaration for `NSDate` properties is `retain`.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You got it.

- Copy returns a new object with a retain count of one.
- assigning it to the *retain* keyword property will increment the retain count.
- autorelease will decrement the retain count.

So your object has the *coreWeStart* property with a retain count of one, which is a copy of the *start* property.